# How do is design following thing in flutter

Tags: flutter, frontend

[Design I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at28X.jpg)

I want this design at the bottom right corner of my Screen i have try multiple thing but the come up with pixel overflow issues.
I also have tried Stack SingleChildScrollView OverflowBox etc but not getting the desired output.

Comment: please give desire design image that you want as output

Comment: show us your code so far.

Comment: 1- Question is unclear / 2-Question needs some code